# UIImage Animation using NSArray - How to wait until array is loaded?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimage, nsarray, grand-central-dispatch

I am loading 6 `NSArray`'s with `UIImage`s in `viewDidLoad`.  I do this using GCD so there is no impact on the user experience.

One issue I am hang is that during the initial transition to this page, the arrays take approx  seconds to load.  I have an animation that kicks off at certain times when the view is rendered.  Depending on the users hardware, the away car run longer than expected in the background.. and not be loaded at the time the animation is called.

So, my general question is, how can I wait to start an animation until I am sure the array is loaded?

Is there a way to check the size of the array, and if it is empty, wait and re-try in 1 second?

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean until your array is loaded? do you get the array image from web? or it's pre-load and saved in your resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
   [self performSelector:@selector(startAnimation) withObject:nil];
}

-(void)startAnimation{
  if ([arrayImage length]==0)
      [self performSelector:@selector(preLoadAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];//repeat every 1 seconds
  else //NSArray is loaded
    {
    //this is your code to animate NSArray.
    // I assume you know how to animate NSArray when you have NSArray already.

    }
}
```